# C# ODBC mysql (null output)

Tags: c#, odbc

can anyone help me? i am getting null output. though data exists in database.

```
string retrivenp = "select emp_email from E_details where emp_ID ='" + c_c + 
  "'AND emp_name = '" + s_s + "'AND emp_address = '" + n_n + 
  "'AND Date_joining = '" + Calendar1.SelectedDate + "'";

using (OdbcCommand comm1 = new OdbcCommand(retrivenp,con))
{
  using (OdbcDataReader read = comm1.ExecuteReader())
  {                          
    while(read.Read())
    {
      url_path = read.ToString();
      Label1.Text = url_path.ToString();
    }                           
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the final query string look like?

Comment: Are you sure the format of the date is compatible with the odbc settings?

Comment: Well while insertion it takes the date value so i guess for retrieval it must work.

Comment: @PaulF Final query string?

Comment: What is the value of the retrivenp string? Have you tried running the query in MySQL workbench or from the command line?

Comment: @PaulF it takes the value. i tried debugging/Breakpoints , it skips the line "   url_path = read.ToString(); " and prints out null.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to convert the reader object to a string & assign to url_path - is that what you really want or do you want to get a particular field from the row - in which case you need to use the GetString(int column) method. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What do you mean by _"it skips the line " url_path = read.ToString(); " and prints out null."_ do you mean it doesn't even get to the line?

Comment: @PaulF thanks ill refer that :)

Comment: yes it doesn't even get to the line. it skips directly .

Comment: If it is not even getting to the line where you assign url_path, then that means the query is returning no rows. So see what the value of retrivenp is & try running that in workbench or from the command-line. You need to be sure that the query is working correctly.

Comment: Alright. ill try that. :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think the string with many quotes is the problem when it will be executed it may give the wrong query 
use command parameters it's better

```
 string retrivenp = "select emp_email from E_details where emp_ID = ? AND emp_name = ? AND emp_address = ? AND Date_joining = ?";

               using (OdbcCommand comm1 = new OdbcCommand(retrivenp,con))
                {
                  comm1.Parameters.Add("@p1", OleDbType.Int).Value =  c_c;
                  comm1.Parameters.Add("@p2", OleDbType.Text).Value =  s_s;
                  comm1.Parameters.Add("@p3", OleDbType.Text).Value =  n_n;
                  comm1.Parameters.Add("@p4", OleDbType.Date).Value =   Calendar1.SelectedDate;

                    using (OdbcDataReader read = comm1.ExecuteReader())
                    {                          
                        while(read.Read())
                        {
                            url_path = read.GetString(0);
                            Label1.Text = url_path.ToString();
                        }  
                         read.Close();


                    }
                }
```

Comment: Hi same.. it is not executing the below part    
while(read.Read())
                        {
                            url_path = read.ToString();
                            Label1.Text = url_path.ToString();
                        }

Comment: hi.. does this play a role in null result?? this enters my search query string (11/23/2016 12:00:00 AM OR 11/23/2016) but in database it is stored in 
2016-11-23 format ..

Comment: i don't think so but if you think that the date format is causing null output remove it from the parameters and try again if it works that means the problem is in the format of the date stored in database not matching with calendar date